# which jar file contain net.opengis.wps.x100 and how can I download it?

Tags: java, opengis

I want to develope a wps process by 52 north and I shoud use `org.n52.wps.server.AbstractSelfDescribingAlgorithm` so this class is inherit from `net.opengis.wps.x100.ProcessDescriptionType`. My question is that which jar file contain this type and please tell me the url for download this jar file?!
My code is:

```
package www.gise.cse.iitb.ac.in;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.n52.wps.io.data.IData;
import org.n52.wps.io.data.binding.literal.LiteralDoubleBinding;
import org.n52.wps.server.AbstractSelfDescribingAlgorithm;

public class AddNumbersAlgo extends org.n52.wps.server.AbstractSelfDescribingAlgorithm {

@Override
public Class getInputDataType(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (arg0.equals("Num1")){
        //return GTVectorDataBinding.class;
        return LiteralDoubleBinding.class;
    }
    if (arg0.equals("Num2")){
        //return GTVectorDataBinding.class;
        return LiteralDoubleBinding.class;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Error: WrongIdentifier");
}

@Override
public Class getOutputDataType(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(arg0.equals("AdditionResult")){
        return LiteralDoubleBinding.class;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Error: Wrong identifier");
}
@Override
public Map<String, IData> run(Map<String, List<IData>> arg0) {

    if (arg0 == null || !arg0.containsKey("Num1")){
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: While allocating Input Parameters");
    }
    if (arg0 == null || !arg0.containsKey("Num2")){
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: While allocating Input Parameters");
    }
    List<IData> datalist = arg0.get("Num1");
    if(datalist == null || datalist.size()!=1){
        throw new RuntimeException("Error:While allocating Input Parameters");
    }

    //Checking for correctness of input
    List<IData> datalist1 = arg0.get("Num2");
    if(datalist1 == null || datalist1.size()!=1){
        throw new RuntimeException("Error:While allocating Input Parameters");
    }
    //Extracting input
            IData Num1 = datalist.get(0);
            double firstNum = ((LiteralDoubleBinding)Num1).getPayload();
            System.out.println(Num1);
            System.out.println(firstNum);

            IData Num2 = datalist1.get(0);
            double secondNum = ((LiteralDoubleBinding)Num2).getPayload();
            System.out.println(Num2);
            System.out.println(secondNum);

            double Result = firstNum + secondNum;
            //double AdditionResult;
            //create the response. In this case a GenericFileDataBinding is used (see this.getOutputDataType(...)
            IData AdditionResult = new LiteralDoubleBinding(Result);

            //new Map created
            Map<String, IData> resultMap = new HashMap<String, IData>();
            //created response added to corresponding identifier (see this.getOutputIdentifiers())
            resultMap.put("AdditionResult", AdditionResult);

            return resultMap;
}

@Override
public List<String> getInputIdentifiers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> identifiers = new ArrayList<String>();
    identifiers.add("Num1");
    identifiers.add("Num2");
    return identifiers;
}

@Override
public List<String> getOutputIdentifiers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> identifiers = new ArrayList<String>();
    identifiers.add("AdditionResult");
    return identifiers;
}
```

and error is:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The type `net.opengis.wps.x100.ProcessDescriptionType` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
> - The type `net.opengis.wps.x100.ProcessDescriptionType` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to find any jars containing what you are searching for.

I found a subversion repository with the files in it. So I

- Checked-out the code from http://geoengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/references/wps/
- Ran `mvn package`

Now you have the jar file:

```
target/wps-1.0.0.jar
```

It is not optimal that you'll have to build it yourself but it solves the problem.

Your code may depend on other jar files as well but I guess that those are in the same repo.

Comment: tnx but I download it before and there is not type like: >net.opengis.wps.x100.ProcessDescriptionType but there is something like >net.opengis.wps10.ProcessDescriptionType and I use it but it didnt solve error

Comment: thanks but by running _mvn package_ this responce occured: [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: net.opengeospatial.wps:wps:jar:1.0.0

Reason: Cannot find parent: cn.geodata.models:references for project: net.openg
ospatial.wps:wps:jar:1.0.0 for project net.opengeospatial.wps:wps:jar:1.0.0

Comment: @iman.tv I see. Checkout everything from trunk level. Build from that level using 'mvn install'. It will probably fail after a while (did for me). Then move down to reference directory and build from there.

Comment: in fact, the above mentioned google code project does serve the net.opengis.wps.* java files. As these are obviously generated XMLBeans bindings, I would recommend to use pre-compiled .jar libraries and not the sources of these. You will never have to change a bit of them and the source code even does not provide valuable insights.

Comment: @matthes You're right. I prefer your solution. The problem was that is was very hard to find any repositories serving the files. I have never worked with any of these projects so I tried to help him to solve the problem at hand. I often search on mvnrepository.com and your code is not present there.

Comment: @maba of course, I would have followed your approach as well if I would not have known the project. So, I just wanted to add the _insder_ knowledge ;) makes life a bit easier.

Comment: @iman.tv You should accept matthes answer instead of mine. His solution is the prefered and correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a maven-managed project. All required artifacts to create such a project are on the public 52north maven repository (including the XML bindings library you mentioned). The following pom.xml should serve well as a project skeleton. It already has the aforementioned maven repository included.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.test.wps-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>wps</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.n52.wps</groupId>
            <artifactId>52n-wps-io</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.n52.wps</groupId>
            <artifactId>52n-wps-algorithm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>n52-releases</id>
            <name>n52-releases</name>
            <url>http://52north.org/maven/repo/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

In general, artifacts of a maven-managed open source project should be accessible on a dedicated or central repository. Otherwise the projects build setup would not be satisfied. So, a general advice would be to first do some investigation on the project structure.